# Purging a active storage attachment will not delete attachment record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a model "Attachment" configures as:

Model

```
 class Attachment< ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many_attached :files
    end
```

COntroller

```
def remove
    @attachment = Attachment.find_by_id(params[:attachment_id])
    @upload = @attachment.files.find(params[:abc_id])
    @upload.purge
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Image was deleted successfully.'
  end
```

View file:

```
<% attachment.files.each do |file| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(file , class: "resize__image", alt: "#{file.filename}"), show_image_attachment_path(file)%>

    <div><%= file.filename %></div>
    <div> <%= link_to  "Remove", attachment_abc_remove_path( attachment, file), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, remote: true %></div>

  <% end %>
```

routes:

```
 resources :attachments, only: [:show, :destroy] do
        member do
          get :show_image
        end
        resources :abc do
          match '/remove', to: 'attachments#remove', via: 'delete'
      end
    end
```

When I try to delete image/images, respective record from "active_storage_blobs" and "active_storage_attachments" gets deleted, whereas record from "Attachment" table will be still present.

Is this expected using active storage? What if I want to delete the respective element from "Account" table as well?
I tried many approaches but was not able to delete the record from "account" table.

Comment: How are you deleting the images? You should have a reference of the account that has those images attached to delete it too if you need to. Show where and how you delete the images to understande you right.

Comment: Updated with code snippets

Comment: Well, you already have the reference to the "Attachment" object. It's reasonable and expected that, if you delete one of the images, the Attachment record is not deleted. Other images will have a missing Attachment object if you delete it after deleting any of the images. If you want to remove the object then do `@attachment.destroy` (it will also purge all it's attachments) or `@attachment.destroy if @attachment.images.empty?` (if you want to destroy it after purging the last image).